# Is there a way to associate certain types of hyperlinks with a browser other than the default one?

Tags: mime-type, default-browser

I would like certain hyperlinks to open with another browser (Chromium) instead of my default browser (Firefox).

Is there a way to associate certain domains or sub-domains to Chromium instead of Firefox?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, the only way to do it would be to write a script and associate it with http/https URLs as a default browser. The script would analyze the URL and call the browser you want according to the criteria you want.